# Unir dois data.frames em um só

Tags: r, data.frame

Tenho uma rotina que o objetivo será sempre o mesmo; Todo dia ela deverá ler um arquivo `xlsx` com todos os preços (série histórica), puxar de um determinado site os preços referentes a última data de atualização, unir esses dois dados em um único data.frame (de forma a atualizar o último dado) e posteriormente transformá-lo em um aquivo excel. Apesar de estar pronta a parte do webscrappe, estou com dificuldades em juntar os dois data.frames.

Minhas tabelas estão assim:

```
 head(df.temp)



Data            2        3
 <NA>         codigo  codigo 
 <NA>         nome1   nome2
 2012-01-01    480   330
 ...           ...   ...
 2017-10-03    480   330
```

E:

```
itens2
Data        2   3 
2017-04-10 400 300
```

Quando eu uso a função `df.melt <- bind_rows(df.temp, itens2)` o R retorna:

```
Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : 
  Can not automatically convert from character to numeric in column "2".
```

as duas tabelas são data.frames. Como resolver?

o objetivo final seria uma tabela assim:

```
  Data            2        3
     <NA>         codigo  codigo 
     <NA>         nome1   nome2
     2012-01-01    480   330
     ...           ...   ...
     2017-10-03    480   330
     2017-04-10    400   300
```

Comment: Sempre que for possível, compartilhe uma parte do seu banco de dados conosco. Escolha algumas linhas dele e informe o resultado do comando `dput(MeuBancoDeDados)`. Isto facilitará muito a vida de quem está disposto a ajudar, pois não será necessário criar um conjunto de dados especial para tentar resolver o problema. Talvez este seja o motivo do gabe não ter conseguido responder esta pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `R` está dizendo que não consegue juntar os data frames porque eles são de tipos diferentes. As colunas de `df.temp` não são valores numéricos, enquanto as de `itens2` são.

Em primeiro lugar, a fim de resolver este problema, eu organizaria os conjuntos de dados, eliminando linhas desnecessárias e dando nomes com algum significado para as suas colunas. Aqui estou assumindo que apenas as duas primeiras linhas de `df.temp` apresentam problemas. Por exemplo,

```
df.temp        <- df.temp[-(1:2), ]
names(df.temp) <- c("Data", "Nome_1", "Nome_2")
```

A primeira linha de código elimina as duas primeiras linhas de `df.temp`, pois elas não servem para nada. A segunda linha de código nomeia as colunas do data frame para algo com significado. Como não sei o objetivo aqui, nomeei elas como "Nome_1" e "Nome_2".

A seguir, é necessário fazer algo similar com `itens2`. Não há dados faltantes aqui. Portanto, apenas renomeie as colunas de `itens2` para que elas tenham os mesmos nomes das colunas de `df.temp`:

```
names(itens2) <- c("Data", "Nome_1", "Nome_2")
```

Agora é só juntar os dois objetos:

```
df.melt <- bind_rows(df.temp, itens2)
```

Answer (score 1):

O erro aparece porque sua tabela tem texto e números na mesma coluna.

`df.temp <- df.temp[complete.cases(df.temp),]` irá sumir com as duas linhas iniciais.

Para acrescentar a nova linha na sua série, as colunas de `df.temp` e `itens2` tem que ser da mesma classe. Pelo erro que você informou, quando fizer `str(df.temp)` e `str(itens2)`, suponho que as categoria das colunas de `df.temp` são data, texto e texto, e as de `itens2` são data, número e número.

Para padronizar as classes, faça `df.temp[,2] <- as.numeric(df.temp[,2])` e `df.temp[,3] <- as.numeric(df.temp[,3])`

Depois disso, você pode juntar as duas fazendo `df.nova <- rbind.data.frame(df.temp, itens2)`

Comment: não deu certo não